# python give column name and write value in separate column as table

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

## my code

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import csv
# encoding=utf8
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')


# example site
page = requests.get('http://www.wintergreenfund.com/reports/top-ten/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
#This will create a list of services:

tname = tree.xpath('//*[@id="colLeft"]//table//tr/td[1]/text()')
tvalue = tree.xpath('//table//tr/td[2]/text()')



print tname
print tvalue

print 'Input the csv file'
csvfile = raw_input("> ")

res = tname,tvalue


#Assuming res is a list of lists
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(res)
```

## my output in csv

Reynolds American Inc.  Consolidated-Tomoka Land Co.    British American Tobacco

8.30%   7.50%   7.10%   6.60%   6.40%   5.90%   5.30%   4.80%   4.70%   4.10%

## Required output same as in website with coulmn name

Ref http://www.wintergreenfund.com/reports/top-ten/

And also unicode is not working .need help on this

## my new code

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import csv

page = requests.get('http://www.wintergreenfund.com/reports/top-ten/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

csvrows = []
for rows in tree.xpath('//*[@id="colLeft"]//table//tr'):
    csvrows.append([rows.xpath('./td[1]/text()'),rows.xpath('./td[2]/text()')])
print csvrows
print 'Input the csv file'
csvfile = raw_input("> ")
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(['Name','Value']) #substitute as appropriate.
    writer.writerows(csvrows)
```

## I am getting value with [' '] in it and also empty [ ]

Comment: Can you please explain what result you are getting ?

Comment: I am getting value as [u'Nestl\xe9 SA, Registered'] ['5.3%'] in separate column ,but i need value "Nestlé SA, Registered 5.3%" same as in above ref website.
It value also require "Nestlé" encoding.please help on this @Anand S Kumar

Comment: Check the answer below.

Comment: i used same program as below,i am getting same error as mentioned above in the csv file .Did you change any line in below program ? 
Please mention the edited part in program @Anand S Kumar

Comment: Just checked again, I changed the code a bit , try the latest one. The latest one saves the results of the xpath and only adds the elements if the result was non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

First thing , if you want to combine two lists at each corresponding index , you should use `zip()` , currently you are creating a tuple of two lists in line - `res = tname,tvalue` - and then writing it as is to the csv.

Also, secondly, you should first use xpath to get each row in the table, and then use xpath to get each required `td` element from it. Rather than using two xpaths as you are using currently.

Example -

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import csv

page = requests.get('http://www.wintergreenfund.com/reports/top-ten/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

csvrows = []
for rows in tree.xpath('//*[@id="colLeft"]//table//tr'):
    row1text = rows.xpath('./td[1]/text()')
    row2text = rows.xpath('./td[2]/text()')
    if row1text and row2text:
        csvrows.append([row1text[0],row2text[0]])
print(csvrows)
print('Input the csv file')
csvfile = input("> ")
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(['Name','Value']) #substitute as appropriate.
    writer.writerows(csvrows)
```